Finding least positive integer $k>1$ such that there exactly exists 100 primes with the form $m!-k$
Suppose $a_n$  as the least positive integer  $k>1$ such that there exactly exists n primes of the form $m!-k$,Find $ a_{100}$.
I firmly believe that $a_n$ must exist for any $n$,is there any clever way to quickly find it?
For example:
$a_5=13$ because if and only if $m \in\{{4, 5, 9, 11, 12}\}$,$m!-13$ are primes,no solutions were found within $k<13$.
$a_{10}=79$ because if and only if $m \in\{5, 6, 8, 9, 15, 21, 30, 38, 42, 47\}$,$m!-79$ are primes,no solutions were found within $k<79$.
$a_{20}=617$ when  $m \in \{6,7,8,12,18,22,23,25,31,34,38,47,144,203,317,359,373,420,476,551\}$.
The first 25 items are as the following: $\{3, 7, 23, 11, 13, 31, 43, 17, 61, 79, 103, 113, 89, 197, 163, 509, 571, 409, 929, 617, 1999, 367, 1583, 1531, 659 \}$.
The first 25 items with their corresponding m:
{1,3,{3}},
{2,7,{4,5}},
{3,23,{5,10,13}},
{4,11,{4,5,6,10}},
{5,13,{4,5,9,11,12}},
{6,31,{5,7,8,20,21,29}},
{7,43,{6,8,11,14,18,21,27}},
{8,17,{4,5,7,9,10,11,12,14}},
{9,61,{5,6,12,13,14,17,18,31,55}},
{10,79,{5,6,8,9,15,21,30,38,42,47}},
{11,103,{5,6,7,10,13,24,48,69,80,86,90}},
{12,113,{5,6,11,19,29,30,31,35,44,45,50,93}},
{13,89,{5,6,7,8,10,11,13,14,15,16,23,42,46}},
{14,197,{6,8,14,19,22,23,28,29,43,49,69,89,113,146}},
{15,163,{6,7,9,11,13,15,16,20,32,33,37,44,55,72,96}},
{16,509,{6,9,10,21,30,32,41,56,105,136,169,255,262,327,432,485}},
{17,571,{6,8,9,15,16,22,23,24,27,32,50,58,68,99,103,134,428}},
{18,409,{6,19,22,24,26,36,41,48,50,82,93,113,117,123,177,190,210,388}},
{19,929,{7,13,19,40,45,48,68,70,74,75,76,108,110,116,154,174,271,462,573}}
{20,617,{6,7,8,12,18,22,23,25,31,34,38,47,144,203,317,359,373,420,476,551}},
{21,1999,{7,8,12,13,14,21,26,41,67,75,93,101,110,195,315,369,740,796,818,1623,1776}}
{22,367,{6,7,8,11,12,13,15,16,17,20,24,36,53,55,69,132,175,230,262,266,277,303}},
{23,1583,{7,8,11,12,13,18,22,28,30,31,44,51,60,81,115,122,150,250,332,431,434,481,516}}
{24,1531,{9,10,12,17,31,40,42,78,102,148,173,258,280,283,292,325,335,664,701,882,888,935,976,1054}}
{25,659,{6,9,11,12,14,18,19,20,23,30,35,39,49,51,53,66,101,103,129,236,239,328,433,569,618}}
Note all items are prime.
Any acceleration techniques to find $ a_{100}$?
The primality test is too time-consuming.

As $k|  m!-k$ when $m>=k$,testing integers $m \in [1,k-1]$ is enough.

As k is the least number,$a_n$  is very likely an odd prime.

There is nothing better than brute force , but for some large $k$ , we might be lucky to find enough primes , it will be difficult however.

I have confused my data with another problem,updated.

We have $a_{25}=659$

@Peter Thanks. $a_{25}=659,m \in {6,9,11,12,14,18,19,20,23,30,35,39,49,51,53,66,101,103,129,236,239,328,433,569,618}$

We also have $a_{22}=367,a_{23}=1583$

Let $p_k$ as the k-th prime,how to calculate the expected value of the prime count of $m!-p_k$?

I begin to doubt that we even reach the $50$-mark. But let us see ...

$a_{24}=1531, m \in {9,10,12,17,31,40,42,78,102,148,173,258,280,283,292,325,335,664,701,882,888,935,976,1054}$

Maybe , you can update the question by posting the $a_i$ in a list. If someone finds another entry , he/she can add it.

For $k=8713$ , there are at least $28$ prime numbers : $$[8, 11, 14, 17, 18, 23, 24, 28, 29, 33, 35, 39, 47, 60, 65, 172, 180, 195, 319, 323, 528, 544, 607, 889, 1660, 2367, 3078, 3655]$$ but I only checked upto about $m\le 6\ 000$.

@ Peter: Thanks.
The primality test is really too time-consuming.

$a_{21}\le 1\ 999$

$a_{28}\le 8\ 713$

$a_{26}\le 843827$. Is $a_{26}$ composite ?

$k=1715771$ gives at least $31$ primes.

I recommend adding this sequence ${a_n}$ to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences!

@Peter:  $a_{26}=5099,{7,8,9,10,19,23,30,37,39,50,54,55,128,190,233,246,1039,1045,1151,1182,1304,1800,2145,2769,3756,4616}$

Sorry,for $a_{26}$,7 should be removed.

@Mrexcel 5099 has only 25 primes then, and we already have a_25 = 659, so a_26 is still unknown, though according to Peter, there must exist a minimum k <= 843827 such that there are exactly 26 primes of the form m! - k.

New solution: $a_{27}=7321,{8,9,11,12,13,14,15,24,32,34,51,53,84,93,116,122,125,170,171,408,502,574,634,1064,1697,2374,5096}$

@Mrexcel Have you tested ALL 1 <= m < k <= 7321? If so how, because that takes some significant computational power? If you haven't, then you only know a_27 <= 7321 assuming 7321 does have exactly 27 primes. My poor old laptop took 21 hours to verify that 5099 has exactly 25 primes, so I don't fancy verifying this one.

@ Simon Goater   For 5600<k<7321,I have 105 primes not tested yet. You are right, I have to test all of them to verify if a_27 = 7321.

6971 was once the greatest hope of  $a_{26}$ ,but only 25 items were found: ${8,9,12,18,20,23,26,30,33,48,83,88,92,109,146,165,179,209,452,1058,1137,1237,4153,4487,6060}$.

$ a_{27} <= 7321 $.

$a_{29}<=7907,{8,9,11,20,21,23,26,46,71,97,112,144,171,183,211,256,398,404,463,588,602,605,829,924,1163,3721,4310,6559,7792}$

@Mrexcel k doesn't HAVE to be prime, though it likely will be as primes have more m values.

For a least k, it should be prime. For example,suppose $b_k$ as prime count of $ m!-k $,and $k=p_1*p_2,p_1<p_2$,then$b_k<=b_{p_1}$

I don't think that's correct. b_p_1 is the prime count of m! - p_1 which is not related to the prime count of m! - k. Or am I missing something?

For example:  we know $ {4,5,6,10}!-11$ are primes,we write it as ${4, 11,{4, 5, 6, 10 }}$

the for multiples of 11, all the terms should be less then 11.

${0,33,{}},{0,55,{}},{2,77,{5,6}},{0,99,{}},{4,121,{6,7,9,10}},{3,143,{6,8,10}},0,165,{}},{1,187,{9}},{3,209,{7,8,10}},{0,231,{}},{2,253,{6,7}},{0,275,{}},{0,297,{}},{4,319,{6,7,9,10}},{2,341,{6,8}},{0,363,{}},{0,385,{}},{2,407,{6,9}},{0,429,{}},{3,451,{6,8,9}},{3,473,{7,8,9}},{0,495,{}}{2,517,{7,9}},{1,539,{6}}$

$k!-p_1*p_2$ maybe prime only if $k<p_1$

My approach to speedy primality testing was to avoid the need for certainty. I know of no reason why numbers of the form N = m! - k might have a significant probability that a composite N would pass a single test
x^N === x mod N

or
x^((N-1)/2) === +-1 mod N

so a weak primality test is sufficient to come up with a good upper bound for a given k for the number of primes of the form m! - k for 1 <= m < k. If that upper bound is not at least the index of the first missing value in those already found, 26 at the time of writing this, then that k can be discarded without the need to check exactly how many of those candidates are definite primes. Otherwise, the process must be repeated with strong primality testing.
I wrote two programs, one which verified the first 25 results, and another which searched for subsequent k using the technique described. I checked all 1 <= m < k <= 4000 but found no new results. I used the GMP library and mpz_probab_prime_p(*, 1) for my 'weak primality' test. Though using a weak primality test makes the program run many times faster than it would if it were checking for definite primality, the runtime of my two programs has been a few days on my old Ivy Bridge 3.2GHz Xeon quad core, using all cores.
My technique could probably be sped up significantly of I enlisted the power of a GPU. I don't think there is currently a good arbitrary precision integer maths library for GPUs though. For this problem, all that is needed is a BigInt modular exponentiation function which I could probably code myself, if I were to invest more time into this exercise. I don't know at this time if a GPU would be good for accelerating a single exponentiation, or it would have to do many in parallel to be efficient as there are parts of the process which must be serialised, which is not ideal for a GPU.
For what it's worth, I also investigated the idea of just calculating m! - k mod p for a ton of small primes p (32 bit), using 'trial division' as a weak primality test. I thought this was a clever idea initially as not only could this be done with 64bit arithmetic, it would be really easy to transpose it to run on the GPU. I tried to estimate how many primes I would need to check to have a good weak primality test. The numbers were very disappointing however. Assuming N behaves like a random BigInt, then the probability it is divisible by small prime p is 1/p. The probability at least one small prime in the list p_1, ..., p_r divides N is
1 - prod_{i=1 to r} (p_i - 1)/p_i

Suppose I want to choose a list of primes to test for k up to 10,000, then if I use the first 10,000 primes over 10,000 I get a probability of just 0.211236 for each N, so only approximately 1 in 5 composite N would be proved, which is of no use. If I use the first 1,000,000 primes over 10,000, it increases only to 0.443085. I include this only as a warning to anyone else who might think of trying to tackle the problem this way.
I'm currently at a loss as to how else this problem can be solved efficiently and would be very interested if anyone could post better ideas. One could use a cluster of nodes using existing tools, but brute forcing this with more computational power won't make huge progress towards finding the likes of a_50 or especially a_100. Some theoretical breakthrough is probably needed.

@RedFive I totally disagree that this does not answer the question. It answers the question as much as the post by gnasher729 in the sense that it describes techniques for accelerating the discovery of elements of the list of a_n in the question description. My technique uses the previously known list of a_n to accelerate discovery of subsequent values. Please can you elaborate on why you think my contribution is of sufficiently low quality to justify your comment.

That was an automated comment from a link I clicked on as a moderator and it doesn't apply so I'm trying to delete it.

Ahh, Ok no problem.

Should be gone now. Apologies for that - I had multiple screens open trying to work though a back-log of flags.

I guess it could look more like an answer to a question about fast primality testing to an AI. Maybe another question would be a good idea looking for a fast compositeness test.

I just realised my claim 'using a weak primality test makes the program run many times faster than it would if it were checking for definite primality,' is dubious since it is checking thousands of composites for each prime k and there are only a few, maybe twenty-something, actual primes. A strong primality test would in most cases exit early if the number was composite.

To find $a_n$, for k = 1, 2, 3 etc. you count how many m there are such that m! - k is a prime. k must not have a prime factor <= m or m! - k is divisible by that prime factor, so m must be smaller than the smallest prime factor of k. If k is a prime then m < k.
We have to test all these m, otherwise we cannot know that there are exactly n primes, so among many other numbers we must test if (k-1)! - k is a prime.
Let p = (k-1)! - k, so $ l = \log_2 p \approx (k-1) \log_2 ((k-1) / e)$. One application of the Miller-Rabin test for a witness a, say a = 2, 3, 5, often requires calculating $a^{(p-1)/2} \mod p$ involving about l products of l bit numbers. Most of these numbers are not primes, so on average only a bit more than one such test is needed. But the chance that we have a prime is also quite small; a small factor higher than 1 / l because the number has no prime factors less than k. So to find 100 primes we need to test a huge number of potential primes. I'd say for n = 100 there is no chance.

I agree more or less , but the chance to get a prime increases by the fact that there is no prime factor less than $m$ , as long as $k$ is a prime and $m<k$. But to find a concrete example with at least $50$ primes will probably already be extremely difficult , finding all primes probably hopeless since there seems to be no example below $10^7$. Concerning the $100$-mark , I see no chance either , not even incomplete.

@Peter Could you kindly elaborate on what you mean when you say 'there seems to be no example below 10^7'. Are you saying you've checked all k up to 10^7 for an example with 50 primes? If so, how? Thanks.

Of course not ! But I checked this range for the number of primes upto $200!-k$ and I did not find a case with enough primes to give hope that $50$ is reachable.

I've checked all m,k up to 3200 and found no cases with 26 or more primes. My current approach is too slow though, so I'm re-thinking.

@SimonGoater I think , the question should better be about "at least xy prime numbers" instead of "exactly xy prime numbers" , at least in this case there is theoretical hope to get spectacular examples.

@Peter I think the problem is fine as it is, but it certainly becomes difficult to find results fast!! I'm giving up the search after checking all 1 <= m < k <= 4000 and not finding any cases with 26 or more primes. Maybe I'll have another go one day if I can think of a much faster way of searching.
